# R finding rows of a data frame where certain columns match those of another

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have an R question that I'm even sure how to word in one sentence, and couldn't find an answer for this yet.

I have two data frames that I would like to 'intersect' and find all rows where column values match in *two* columns. I've tried connecting two intersect() and which() statements with &&, but neither has given me what I want yet.

Here's what I mean. Let's say I have two data frames:

```
> testData
               Email     Manual Campaign Bounced Opened Clicked ClickThru Unsubscribed
1 stack@overflow.com EIFLS0LS        1       0      0       0         0            0
2 stack@exchange.com EIFLS0LS        1       0      0       0         0            0
3     data@frame.com EIFLS0LS        1       0      0       0         0            0
4    block@quote.com EIFLS0LS        1       0      0       0         0            0
5          ht@ml.com EIFLS0LS        1       0      0       0         0            0
6     tele@phone.com EIFLS0LS        1       0      0       0         0            0

> testBounced
               Email Campaign
1 stack@overflow.com        1
2 stack@overflow.com        2
3     data@frame.com        2
4    block@quote.com        1
5          ht@ml.com        1
6        lap@top.com        1
```

As you can see, there are some values in the column Email that intersect, and some from the column Campaign that intersect. I want all of the rows from testData in which BOTH columns match.

ie:

```
               Email     Manual Campaign Bounced Opened Clicked ClickThru Unsubscribed
1 stack@overflow.com EIFLS0LS        1       0      0       0         0            0
2    block@quote.com EIFLS0LS        1       0      0       0         0            0
3          ht@ml.com EIFLS0LS        1       0      0       0         0            0
```

EDIT:

My goal in finding these columns is to be able to update a row in the original column. So the final output that I would like is:

```
> testData
               Email     Manual Campaign Bounced Opened Clicked ClickThru Unsubscribed
1 stack@overflow.com EIFLS0LS        1       1      0       0         0            0
2 stack@exchange.com EIFLS0LS        1       0      0       0         0            0
3     data@frame.com EIFLS0LS        1       0      0       0         0            0
4    block@quote.com EIFLS0LS        1       1      0       0         0            0
5          ht@ml.com EIFLS0LS        1       1      0       0         0            0
6     tele@phone.com EIFLS0LS        1       0      0       0         0            0
```

My apologies if this is a duplicate, and thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT2::

I ended up just using a for loop, nothing great, but doesn't feel efficient. The dataset was small enough to do it quickly, though. If anyone has a quick, R-style way to do it, I'd be happy to see it!

Comment: `merge(testData, testBounced)`

Comment: sorry about the close comment, I hadn't seen the comment at the bottom of SenorO's answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `data.tables` and key by the columns you want to match, then you can accomplish your goal in one line:

```
    tData[tBounce, Bounced := 1L]
```

---

#### Here is the full process:

```
library(data.table)
keys <- c("Email", "Campaign")
tData <- data.table(testData, key=keys)
tBounce <- data.table(testBounce, key=keys)

tData[tBounce, Bounced := 1L]
```

#### Results:

```
tData

                Email   Manual Campaign Bounced Opened Clicked ClickThru Unsubscribed
1:    block@quote.com EIFLS0LS        1       1      0       0         0            0
2:     data@frame.com EIFLS0LS        1       0      0       0         0            0
3:          ht@ml.com EIFLS0LS        1       1      0       0         0            0
4: stack@exchange.com EIFLS0LS        1       0      0       0         0            0
5: stack@overflow.com EIFLS0LS        1       1      0       0         0            0
6:     tele@phone.com EIFLS0LS        1       0      0       0         0            0
>
```

Comment: I knew there had to be an easy way. Thanks for introducing me to that package!

Comment: +1: clever use of X[Y, foo] syntax

Comment: This is excellent!! I had done something similar to select on one column using "match", but trying to extend that to selecting (or subsetting or whatever we want to call this) on > 1 column really stymied me.

Comment: I am very interested in this solution. In my case, I would like to find all rows where column values of a data frame match in three columns of another data frame. But, I don't understand why there is "Bounced :=1L". Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @Marine, probably best to open a new question and linking back to this one

Answer (score 9):

You want the function `merge`.

`merge` is commonly used to merge two tables by one similar common, but the `by` argument can allow multiple columns:

```
merge(testData, testBounced, by=c("Email", "Campaign"))
```

All pairs of `Email` and `Campaign` that don't match will be discarded by default. That's controllable by the arguments `all.x` and `all.y`, which default to `FALSE`.

The default argument for `by` is `intersect(names(x, y))`, so you technically don't need to specify the columns in this case, but it's good for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I realize I wasn't being clear- My goal is to be able to change values of other columns in the original table (in this case testData) on the columns that work. I'll update the original question.