# Substitute DT1.x with DT2.y when DT1.x and DT2.x match in R

Tags: r, data.table

I want to do this using data tables in R.

So I start with this

```
     dtMain
           Name      state
    1: CompanyC         CA
    2: CompanyM         MN
    3: CompanyC1 California
    4: CompanyT         TX

     statesFile
       stateExpan state
    1:      Texas    TX
    2:  Minnesota    MN
    3: California    CA
```

Where `dtMain$State == statesFile$state`, I want to replace `dtMain$State` with `statesFile$stateExpan`
and get this

```
      dtMain
           Name      state
    1: CompanyA California
    2: CompanyB  Minnesota
    3: CompanyC California
    4: CompanyD      Texas
```

Here's code to create the 2 files

```
library(data.table)
dtMain <- data.table(Name  = c("CompanyA"  ,"CompanyB","CompanyC","CompanyD"),
                 state = c("CA","MN","California","TX"))
statesFile <- data.table( stateExpan = c("Texas","Minnesota","California"),
                          state = c("TX","MN","CA"))
```

My problem is the next level of this one
[R finding rows of a data frame where certain columns match those of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888764/r-finding-rows-of-a-data-frame-where-certain-columns-match-those-of-another?noredirect=1&lq=1)
and I am looking for a data table solution.

Comment: You should use words to explain the rules for the transformation, not simply show input and output

Comment: @ytk Not a dupe of that, I think, since this is about modifying dtMain, not merging to create a new table.

Comment: Anyway, the answer is `dtMain[statesFile, on=.(state), state := i.stateExpan ]` I'll see if I can find a more suitable dupe. You could also have a look at the user-written examples for this: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/data.table/4976/joins-and-merges/17560

Comment: Thanks this answers my question. I was using                    dtMain[statesFile$state, state := statesFile$stateExpan]                                         which works but destroys the original dt order.

Comment: Yeah, generally best to avoid $ with data.tables, where it's not needed and can create confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an update join:

```
dtMain[statesFile, on=.(state), state := i.stateExpan ]
```

The `i.*` prefix indicates that it's from the `i` table in `x[i, on=, j]`. It is optional here.

See `?data.table` for details.

Comment: I couldn't find a dupe, so posting...