# Ifelse in R with multiple categorical conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table, conditional-statements

I have a data set, `dt.train2` with  1500 different observations and 130 variables. One of them is `languages` and it can be `english`, `french`, `arabic`...

I want to create a `ifelse` string that gives attributes `1` for `english`, `2` for `french`, `3` for `spanish` and `0` for anything else. I have no idea how to do it.

```
dt.train2[, language_string := ifelse(language == "english", 
                                      1, 
                                      ifelse(language == "french", 
                                             2, 
                                             ifelse(language == "spanish",3)]
```

I'm using this to run linear model about sales.

Comment: You're just missing the final else condition, `language == "spanish",3, 0)`, you need that **`, 0`**.

Comment: That said, this seems like a terrible way to prepare for a linear model, unless you really think that whatever language effect there is, the French effect is two times the English effect, and the Spanish effect three times the English effect.

Comment: I'd say make a table and do an update join https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587214/substitute-dt1-x-with-dt2-y-when-dt1-x-and-dt2-x-match-in-r

Comment: You're completely right!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there with the `ifelse()`, you just need the final `else` result (and a couple missing closing parentheses).

```
dt.train2[, language_string := ifelse(
  language == "english", 1,
    ifelse(language == "french", 2,
      ifelse(language == "spanish", 3, 0)
    )
  )
]
```

---

A couple other ways you could do this:

Make a lookup table and join:

```
# sample data
dt = data.table(language = c("english", "french", "spanish", "arabic", "chinese", "pig latin"))


lookup = data.table(language = c("english", "french", "spanish"),
                    language_string = c(1, 2, 3))

dt2 = merge(dt, lookup, by = "language", all.x = TRUE)
dt2[is.na(language_string), language_string := 0]
```

The above lookup table method is probably the nicest for scalability. However, for such a small number of encodings, you could also just set each of them:

```
# start with the default, 0
dt[, language_string := 0 ]
# then do each of the exceptions
dt[lanuage == "english", language_string := 1]
dt[language == "french", language_string := 2]
dt[language == "spanish", language_string := 3]
```

Comment: Fyi, one idiom for a lookup is like `dt[, v := 0][lookup, on=.(language), v := language_string]` so that the column is added by reference instead of building a new table.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments that if this is for a linear model, it is a bad way to go about it. If you insist on languages as predictors, it is better practice to make a series of dummy variables. In this case, you would add 3 predictors ("english", "french", "arabic") which all take values of 0 or 1.

Either way, here is my *dplyr* take on the problem, which utilizes a `CASE WHEN` SQL-style syntax and is easier to read.

```
require(tidyverse)
dt.train2 <- dt.train2 %>%
          mutate(language_string = case_when(language == "english" ~ 1,
                                             language == "french" ~ 2,
                                             language == "spanish" ~ 3,
                                             TRUE ~ 0))
```

Comment: You're right. I'm really new to this. I'll try your solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Gregor Thanks for catching that. I edited it with the catch-all of `TRUE ~ 0` for other cases.

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
 t <- 'es'
 tt <- (if (t == 'en') 1 else if (t == 'fr') {2} else if (t == 'es') 3 else 0)
 tt
 [1] 0
```

you can then apply it to like a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(l=c('en', 'fr', 'es', 'sthelse'))
df$lnum <- sapply(df$l, function(t){(if (t == 'en') 1 else if (t == 'fr') {2} else if (t == 'es') 3 else 0)})
df
        l lnum
1      en    1
2      fr    2
3      es    3
4 sthelse    0
```

Comment: Could alternately write this algebraically, `(t=="en") + 2*(t=="fr") + 3*(t=="es")`, so that it's vectorized.

Comment: Debated downvoting (didn't), but the un-vectorized way is really terrible, even on a few hundred rows it will be noticeably slow.  And the `unlist(lapply())` is overly complicated - just use `sapply` if you're going to do that.  But vectorized `ifelse()` (or Frank's clever vectorized solution) are much better.

Comment: you're quite right indeed - changed it to sapply. Thanks!

Comment: Or just `c(en=1, fr=2, es=3)[t]`

Answer (score 0):

```
language_options <- c("english", "french", "spanish", ...)
dt.train2[, language_string := match(language, language_options)]
```